# Overloading input / output operators

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading, cout

When overloading the input or output operators (>> or <<) , I see that the function takes two arguments, a reference to an iostream object and a reference to whatever object we wish to input or output. An operator<< example for a Matrix object :

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Matrix& matrix);
```

When calling this function we only need to pass the Matrix object, for example :

```
Matrix m1;
cout<<m1;
```

What about the other ostream object argument? How does this work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The other argument is `cout` itself. The call becomes `operator<<(cout, m1)`.

If the operator only took one argument, you could write `<< m1;` as a complete statement, which you cannot.

Comment: but is cout not the return ostream& from the function? I still see only one argument m1 passed to the function

Comment: @Engineer999: A binary operator like `cout<<m1` has two operands, `cout` and `m1`. If the operator is defined as a non-member function (as it is here), the two operands become two function arguments.

Comment: @Engineer999 `cout` is the first argument to the function and *also* the returned object. That means that both the expression `cout` and the expression `cout << m1` represent the `cout` stream.

Comment: @Engineer999: How could you return `cout` if you don't take it as an argument and you don't reference `cout`?

Comment: I've just been getting confused as the cout is to the left of <<. I always thought that arguments to a function must be put in the exact same way as the function is declared. For example <<(cout, m1) makes sense to me. I didn't know that the compiler looks at the operands and decides where they go.

Answer (score 1):

> What about the other ostream object argument? How does this work?

If the compiler finds:

```
a = b <op> c;
```

(where `<op>` can be +, -, ==, >>, etc), the compiler will try the following resolutions:

```
a = operator <op>(b, c); // (1)
a = b.operator <op> (c); // (2)
```

This depends on the type of operator (for example, + is a binary operator and cannot be implemented in form (2)) and implementations available (the code you write and the resolution priority).

For operator << (your example above), these pieces of code are equivalent:

1:

```
Matrix m1;
cout<<m1;
```

2:

```
Matrix m1;
operator<<(cout, m1);
```

For native data types, std:::istream offers a member implementation:

```
int i;
cout.operator<<(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this case:

```
cout<<m1
```

Here cout is the first argument, m1 is second.
The return value of this method call is not captured by your code.

Case 2:

```
cout << m1 <<  m2;
```

Here there will be two calls to operator.
Return of the first call is passed as argument of next call.